# Is there simple way to detect keyboard and mouse button being pressed and held in Java without application focus?

Tags: java, mouseevent

I'm trying to write quite simple program in Java - when user click left mouse button it will autoclick until released, but only if toggled before with keyboard key. I have no problem with this autofire part, but I dont know how to detect keyboard press, and mouse button press when my aplication doesn't have focus. Is there some simply way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a side note - Are you creating macro for game?

**You can download jNativeHook https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/ and hook global listener to globalScreen that way it doesn't matter if you have focus over application.**

Then you can use it like normal swing/fx listener.

### CAUTION

**Make sure that you unhook it correctly otherwise after some hooks it might be blocked and you will have to restart the PC to hook it again (fixed in future release).**

If you are doing a macro for a game you might have a problem when focused on window - some fullscreen games and even in windowed mode, at least from my personal experience. Robot will also fail in some games to execute event.

Comment: The unhook/blocking issue should be resolved in 1.2, RC 1 is ready and should be released this weekend.

Comment: @Alex Barker thats really good news.Can i have more details what was causing this behaviour?

Comment: Its related to the mutex checking in the Windows [NativeThread.c](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/1.1/src/native/windows/NativeThread.c) file.  You can compare the thread safety code to the updated [hook_thread.c](https://github.com/kwhat/libuiohook/blob/master/src/windows/hook_thread.c) to see the exact changes.  Please open a bug report if you would be interested in a back-ported solution.

Comment: @Alex Barker Thanks for info.And also thank you for this awesome library you provided to the community!