# How to make swing/java keep running even when user doesn't click on it

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouselistener, keylogger

Let's imagine I have a program like the source below:

```
public class Main extends JFrame implements MouseListener {
    public Main() {
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("clicked!");
    }
}
```

in order to run this program and have out output (in this case when  user clicked on the jframe shows "clicked") the user has to specifically click the jframe but I want to say if user clicked anywhere show me this output but I don't know how to make the program do that

Comment: You mean you want to click anywhere on screen (even on the desktop or other applications) and detect the click?

Comment: Yes exactly, but it's not just click, at some point I want the program just be underground and just give me information about what the user did when the program wasn't up on his/her screen. in this example I wanna know if the user did click somewhere around the screen or not while the program was running underground

Comment: You know that this question has been asked on Stack Overflow many times before? Please get in the habit of searching before posting a question.

Comment: I did search for but I couldn't find it, because I didn't know what I was exactly looking for and I searched multiple times for it with different vocabulary but still there was nothing to use. at the end I didn't have too much of a choice, so I just asked in here. this community is for asking QUESTIONS, I don't know why some of you can't just stand some broken questions that come from noobies. I get it, it'll make the site messy but it wouldn't be so hard just to give me the link. Which in this case rwitserloot helped me out.

Comment: You got the link -- it was in my second comment identifying the duplicate, and it's now plastered at the top of your question. Stack Overflow is as useful as it is **because** people are strict about what gets asked and answered here. Read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help). You agreed to all of that when you first posted here, so stop taking it personally -- this isn't facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a mouselistener onto your JFrame; of course this only fires if a click happens **inside your jframe**.

A good OS won't let you do this without registering as an accessibility tool or otherwise getting root access; seeing clicks in other apps is a security leak.

Java is not a great tool for writing OS-specific programs, and 'I want to listen to clicks anywhere on any screen and in any app' is quite OS specific.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496292/java-detect-mouse-clicks-anywhere-on-screen) for some hacks you can try if you insist on doing this with java.