# Detecting MouseClicks without JFrame

Tags: java, mouselistener

Currently stuck on how to create an executable jar file that would run in the background of my pc and detect if my mouse is down. I know JFrame is a one method of doing so, but that's visible on my screen, even though I set it to invisible it appears to disable it completely.

Here's my code so far, is there a another method I could use that isn't JFrame related?

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

MyFrame(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(500,500);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyChar() =='q'){
        this.setVisible(false);
    }
    if(e.getKeyChar()=='l'){
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java - Detect Mouse Clicks Anywhere On Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496292/java-detect-mouse-clicks-anywhere-on-screen)

Comment: You can’t do it without using some kind of native library - JNI/JNA

Comment: [Example to play with using JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/blob/2.2/doc/Mouse.md). You can get the library JAR file [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.1stleg/jnativehook/2.1.0/source-code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download `jNativeHook` and hook the global listener to `globalScreen`.

you can use it as a normal swing listener.

Here is the link:

https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

By using this library you achieve a wide range of functions to control the mouse events!!